# StiJsViewer not defined

Tags: asp.net-mvc, report, reporting, stimulsoft

I encounter this error when implementing reporting with stimulsoft in asp .net mvc. please help.

The Error is this: "StiJsViewer is not defined"

I tried using tutorials and searched in google. But this problem still exist.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.